# Stata cumulative sum with duplicate records

Tags: loops, stata

```
clear 
input input record1 record2   value       str8 sdate
  1      1       0        2         "1/1/2010"
  2      1       0        2         "1/1/2010"
  3      1       0        3         "1/3/2010"
  4      1       0        3        "1/3/2010"
  5      1       0        3        "1/3/2010"
  6      0       1        -3        "1/5/2010"
  7      0       1        -3         "1/5/2010"
  8      1       0        2        "1/5/2010"
  9      0       1        1         "1/7/2010" 
 end 
 gen date = daily(sdate, "MDY") 
 format date %td
```

A MWE of what I have is a variable `recordi` for each individual in my data that is `1` if they are involved in that value. I want to create a variable for each individual that cumulatively sums that days value with the final value from the day before. Leaving the following output.

```
input record1 record2   value   date          record1dailysum    record2dailysum
  1      1       0        2     1/1/2010            2                .
  2      1       0        2     1/1/2010            2                .
  3      1       0        3     1/3/2010            5                .
  4      1       0        3     1/3/2010            5                .
  5      1       0        3     1/3/2010            5                .
  6      0       1        -3    1/5/2010            .               -3
  7      0       1        -3    1/5/2010            .               -3
  8      1       0        2     1/5/2010            7                .
  9      0       1        1     1/7/2010            .               -2
```

I have many records so I have used a loop to create these values. This is what I have tried to create `recorddailysumi`

```
qui forval i = 1/2
    by date: egen record`i'dailysum = value + value[_n-1] if record`i' == 1
}
```

Lastly, I would like to shift the values down by one date so for `record1` the values for `1/3/2010` would be the values now in `1/1/2010`, etc.

It is not an option to condense the data to create a unique record by date and record and merge back (at least that is a last resort because it is a huge and messy dataset).

Comment: In addition to detailed answers elsewhere, note the injunction "Explicit subscripting (using _N and _n), which is commonly used with generate, should not be used with egen" e.g. http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?egen Your syntax happens to be illegal too, as there is no function specified, but  subscripts and `egen` don't mix any way. This is  because `egen` often `sort`s temporarily, so sort order may not be maintained during calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some errors in your code:

- missing `{` at the end of your `forvalues` line
- `by date` implies that you want to treat each unique date as a group. You don't actually want this. You want to `sort date` and then run your code by `record[i]` (given the structure of your data).
- The (probably) more normal approach is to have a single field called `record` that is equal to 1, 2, ..., in which case you would simply code `bys record (date): ...` (more later).
- Note that the `sum()` function for `generate` (not `egen`) gives a cumulative sum.

Regarding the request: It's not clear what you gain by having duplicated observations in your data, nor what you gain by repeating your cumulative sum across observations. Why not just `duplicates drop [varlist]`? Or if you need to keep all observations, tagging the *unique* observations would likely be of more utility, I would assume.

Finally, *"I want to create a variable for each individual that cumulatively sums that days value with the final value from the day before. Leaving the following output."* is at odds with *"Lastly, I would like to shift the values down by one date so for record1 the values for 1/3/2010 would be the values now in 1/1/2010, etc."*

One solution, maintaining your structure:

```
clear 
input input record1 record2   value       str8 sdate
  1      1       0        2         "1/1/2010"
  2      1       0        2         "1/1/2010"
  3      1       0        3         "1/3/2010"
  4      1       0        3        "1/3/2010"
  5      1       0        3        "1/3/2010"
  6      0       1        -3        "1/5/2010"
  7      0       1        -3         "1/5/2010"
  8      1       0        2        "1/5/2010"
  9      0       1        1         "1/7/2010" 
end 

// tag unique obs (consider instead duplicates drop record1 record2 value sdate, force)
egen tag = tag(record1 record2 value sdate)

// generate stata data
gen date = daily(sdate, "MDY") 
format date %td 

// fixed loop
sort date
forval i = 1/2 {
    gen record`i'dailysum = sum(value) if record`i' == 1 & tag == 1
}

// if you must have duplicated sums, you can replace by group
forvalues i = 1/2 {
    clonevar record`i'dailysum2 = record`i'dailysum
    bys record`i' value date (record`i'dailysum2): replace record`i'dailysum2 = record`i'dailysum2[1]
}
sort record2 date record1 date
li, sepby(record1) noobs
```

with the result

```
  +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
  | input   record1   record2   value      sdate   tag        date   record..   record..   record..   record.. |
  |------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  |     2         1         0       2   1/1/2010     0   01jan2010          .          .          2          . |
  |     1         1         0       2   1/1/2010     1   01jan2010          2          .          2          . |
  |     3         1         0       3   1/3/2010     1   03jan2010          5          .          5          . |
  |     5         1         0       3   1/3/2010     0   03jan2010          .          .          5          . |
  |     4         1         0       3   1/3/2010     0   03jan2010          .          .          5          . |
  |     8         1         0       2   1/5/2010     1   05jan2010          7          .          7          . |
  |------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  |     6         0         1      -3   1/5/2010     1   05jan2010          .         -3          .         -3 |
  |     7         0         1      -3   1/5/2010     0   05jan2010          .          .          .         -3 |
  |     9         0         1       1   1/7/2010     1   07jan2010          .         -2          .         -2 |
  +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

However, if this was my project, I would surely look into something like this:

```
// AN ALTERNATIVE APPROACH

clear 
input input record1 record2   value       str8 sdate
  1      1       0        2         "1/1/2010"
  2      1       0        2         "1/1/2010"
  3      1       0        3         "1/3/2010"
  4      1       0        3        "1/3/2010"
  5      1       0        3        "1/3/2010"
  6      0       1        -3        "1/5/2010"
  7      0       1        -3         "1/5/2010"
  8      1       0        2        "1/5/2010"
  9      0       1        1         "1/7/2010" 
end 

// recode record
gen record = .
forvalues i = 1/2 {
    replace record = `i' if record`i' == 1
}
drop record?

gen date = daily(sdate, "MDY") 
format date %td 

// drop duplicates
duplicates drop record value date , force

// gen daily sum by record (loop not required due to single variable structure)
bysort record (date): gen dailysum = sum(value)

li, sepby(record) noobs
```

yielding

```
  +----------------------------------------------------------+
  | input   value      sdate   record        date   dailysum |
  |----------------------------------------------------------|
  |     1       2   1/1/2010        1   01jan2010          2 |
  |     3       3   1/3/2010        1   03jan2010          5 |
  |     8       2   1/5/2010        1   05jan2010          7 |
  |----------------------------------------------------------|
  |     6      -3   1/5/2010        2   05jan2010         -3 |
  |     9       1   1/7/2010        2   07jan2010         -2 |
  +----------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

Shifting the values down by one date is an easy task in the second example:

```
// shift the values down by one date
bysort record (date): gen dailysum2 = dailysum[_n-1]
```

In the first example, the following should work:

```
forvalues i = 1/2 {
    bys tag record`i' (date): gen record`i'dailysumshift = record`i'dailysum[_n-1] if tag == 1
}
```

Comment: This is great but for completeness can you add the code to shift the values down by one date as stated in the question